# Custom package log level ignored

Tags: grails, log4j

I'm trying to log via `log.info("something")` in my service class `net.ted.grailsapp.TaskExecuter`. Though i set the logging for the `net.ted.grailsapp` package to `info` it does not print any log message.

When i set the root logging level to `info` instead of `error` it prints the message to `stdout`. Unfortunately it also prints every other `info`-message from other frameworks which i rather want to filter out.

Any idea whats wrong?

```
log4j.main = {
    // Example of changing the log pattern for the default console appender:
    //
    appenders {
        console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%c{2} [%p] - %m%n')
    }

    root {
        error 'stdout'
    }

    info stdout:
        'net.ted.grailsapp',
        'org.apache.cxf'

    error stdout:
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
        'org.springframework',
        'org.hibernate',
        'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
info 'grails.app.services'
```

That should allow `log.info()` to log within *all* services. I don't know how to get it down to a specific service.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31030174/1123743) is a complete example for package specific logging.